# HitHighlightedSummary is very short (compared to same query for OnPrem) or contains no data for list item SPO search results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

I noticed that the **HitHighlightedSummary** is very short (compared to same query for OnPrem) or contains no data for **list item** SPO search results.

The issue seems to be scoped tenant wide.

Has anyone encountered this challenge so far?